# Android multistep welcome screen (tutorial for using the app)

Tags: android

How to implement those popular welcome guides, where you have:
3-5 slides (with those little dots indicating the process), in the end button with something like "got it" (take me to the app & never show again).
Here is example (Walkthroughs with Twine):
https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/50723/android-multi-step-wizard-examples

Comment: I cant figure out between the alternatives:
1. Activity, where each slide is fragment and the dots are regular buttons
OR
2. There is dedicated design pattern for this (because it`s so popular and looks the same everywhere...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) and multiple contained View's or [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)s will help you achieve this. For the indicator you can use [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/).

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use `ViewPager`  here is a good library will help you to implement that:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator
or you can use a horizontal `GridViews` and set its column to 1 or using tabs and here is a library for horizontal `gridView` :
https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview

Comment: Thanks for the answer